# Hide tooltips when select items has value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to disable tooltips when `select` dropdown list has choose value?

Sample code:

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control"
        ng-model="v.c" 
        ng-options="name for name in candidates"
        tooltip="help description">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try `tooltop="{{!v.c && 'help description'}}"`

Comment: @Chandermani : doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (using jquery)

html:

```
<div>
    <select id="select_1" class="form-control"
        ng-model="v.c" 
        ng-options="name for name in candidates"
        tooltip="help description">
        <option value="">...</option>
        <option value="1"> 1</option>
        <option value="1"> 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('#select_1').change(function(){
        var checked = $(this).find('option:checked').length > 0;
        if (checked){
            if (!$(this).attr('data-tip1'))
                $(this).attr('data-tip1',$(this).attr('tooltip'));

            $(this).attr('tooltip','');
        }else{
            $(this).attr('tooltip',$(this).data('tip1'));
        }


    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle by using one controller variable 
Controller

```
$scope.mytooltip="help description";
```

write one watch function for 'v.c' model variable,if variable is empty bind your tooltip else bind empty.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control"
        ng-model="v.c" 
        ng-options="name for name in candidates"
       tooltip="{{mytooltip}}">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share an example of watch function?

Comment: $scope.$watch('v.c', function (value) {
       if($scope.v.c==""){//tool tip}else{//no toll tip}
    })